# React JS: Array is not being passed to state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios, use-state

I have the array of objects called 'array'. When I try to pass it to the useState 'rows' to use it in my program, the data is not being copied to the rows state and it's giving me an empty array.

```
const project = () => {
 const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

 const function = () => {

 var array = [{username: "username1"}, {username: "username2"}];
 
 console.log(array);
 //The output here is: 
 //(2) [{…}, {…}]
 //0: {username: 'username1'}
 //1: {username: 'username2'}
 //length: 2
 //[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

  array.map((row) => {
    return setRows(rows => [...rows, row])          
            
   })

  console.log(rows)
 //The output here is: 
 //[]
 //length: 0
 //[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

 //Another method tried
 //setRows(array)
//console.log(rows)
 //The output here is:
 //[]
 //length: 0
 //[[Prototype]]: Array(0)


 }

return (....);

}

export default project;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is not the right way here to do this.

Use `forEach` or `for` loop instead of it.

try this:

```
array.forEach(row => {
    setRows(rows => [...rows, row]);
});
```

The following documentation will help you understand the usage of `map` better.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp